# syntax highlighting breaks on escaped newlines / characters

Tags: syntax-highlighting

for example, here I am editing the i3 config file. It shows syntax error just because a line is broken into multiple lines, with newline's being escaped.

[image: vim editor: editing i3wm config file, syntax anomaly]

I have noticed that syntax highlighting breaks on other escape characters too. for example `"abc \" def"` breaks syntax at the middle `"`.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a new file with syntax on and `:set filetype=i3config`.
2. Type the following text:

```
exec --no-startup-id kitty
exec --no-startup-id \
    kitty
```

Notice the difference in syntax in the two lines.

Comment: Welcome to Vim. In order to help people to reproduce your  problem could you: add a small example of a text that trigger a warning (not as screenshot but as text), tell us what is the filetype of the buffer (``:set ft?``)?

Comment: When I follow your instructions I get no colorization at all. Do you have a plugin installed for i3config?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I have only one plugin, that is `gruvbox` colorscheme. Nothing I have specific to filetype `i3config`. My `.vimrc` sources `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` and I have done only few extra configuration outside it.

Comment: Sorry Amith I can't reproduce the behavior. Can you tell us which version of vim your are using. Are you using a Vim distribution like Amix or SpaceVim

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt my vim version is 8.2. I have gvim installed from debian testing repo. Here is my vimrc in completion if it helps: https://pastebin.com/su1TWVww . thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

This code uses the [`i3ConfigLineCont`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/559f230fd618e51d7986d87217ff38a2eac73cef/runtime/syntax/i3config.vim#L183) rule.

```
syn region i3ConfigLineCont start=/^.*\\$/ end=/^.*$/ ...
```

`end=/^.*$/` needs to be `end=/^[^\\]*$/` to fix the highlight error. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/10600) with this fix.